# If Else Statement in SQL Server stored procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have 3 conditions here.

1. To read only 9 characters of LotNo.(it may consist up to 10 characters)
2. Omit dot if the last(9th) character is dot(.)
3. But some LotNo have less than 9 characters and we need to remove dot if the last character is a (.)

I'm using If else statement in the stored procedure. I used Substring to get the 1st 9 characters. The result looks good for the 1st two condition but it's not working for the 3rd condition.

```
DECLARE @ShortWaferLotNo VARCHAR(50)

set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@WaferLotNo, 0, 10);

if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.'
begin
  set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@WaferLotNo, 0, 9);
end
else if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.'
begin
  set @ShortWaferLotNo = STUFF(@WaferLotNo,DATALENGTH(@WaferLotNo), 1, '') 
end
else 
begin
  set  @ShortWaferLotNo='' 
end
```

PPLT2.01.B.B.B ( WaferLotNo) -->PPLT2.01 ( read only 1st 9 character and omit dot if the 9th character is a dot.

PQ1H3.1. ---->  PQ1H3.1 ( Omit last dot)

PQ1H. ---->PQ1H. (Omit the last dot)

Comment: you seem to have  -- if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.' -- in there twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to substring based on the length.

```
   DECLARE @ShortWaferLotNo VARCHAR(50)

select @ShortWaferLotNo = 'PQ1H3.1.'

set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@ShortWaferLotNo, 0, 10)

print @ShortWaferLotNo

if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.'
begin
  set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@ShortWaferLotNo, 0, len(@ShortWaferLotNo));
end
else 
begin
  set  @ShortWaferLotNo='' 
end

print @ShortWaferLotNo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I managed to solve it like below : 

begin
declare @WaferLotNo as varchar(100)
declare @ShortWaferLotNo as varchar(100)
select @WaferLotNo='PJY.9.B.B.' --PQ1H3.1.
if DATALENGTH(@WaferLotNo)>=9
    set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@WaferLotNo, 0, 10);
    if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.'
    begin
        set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@WaferLotNo, 0, 9);
    end 
if DATALENGTH(@WaferLotNo)<9
        set @ShortWaferLotNo = SUBSTRING(@WaferLotNo, 0, 9);
        if RIGHT(@ShortWaferLotNo, 1) = '.'
        begin
           set @ShortWaferLotNo = STUFF(@WaferLotNo,DATALENGTH(@WaferLotNo), 1, '') 
        end
end

print @ShortWaferLotNo
```